# How can I prioritise a div more than another one

Tags: html, css

I want two text-boxes next to each other. The first one should give space to the second more important one.

How is that possible without giving fixed widths and using text-overflow: ellipsis on the first one?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/by2e9uej/

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#test1 {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#test1 > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
#test2 {
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;   /* Opera */
    text-overflow:    ellipsis;   /* IE, Safari (WebKit) */
    overflow:hidden;              /* don't show excess chars */
    white-space:nowrap;           /* force single line */
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1">
  <div id="test2">long text standing in here</div>
  <div id="test3">more important text in here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are the contents being retrieved dynamically?

Comment: yes they are out of a database

Comment: What do you mean by give space?  Are they both meant to stay on one line and what do you want to do with any overflow?

Comment: in the end it should look like that https://jsfiddle.net/by2e9uej/2/ without fixed width

Comment: Why not use what you used in the fiddle? You already achieved what you want.

Comment: You should set a dynamic width calculated by multiplication in JavaScript (something like text length * char font size).

Comment: its a dynamic content and a responsive webpage so fixed widths are not a solution for me in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Flexbox and set `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` on first child div.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#test1 {
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
}
#test1 > div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#test2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1">
  <div id="test2">long text standing in here</div>
  <div id="test3">more important text in here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the browsers you have to support can support [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), go with flexbox.

I've made some example html for you to show you what it does.
The magic css properties here are: `display: flex`, `flex-direction: row`, `flex: 1`, and `flex-basis: 200px`

```css
.container
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.container > .item
{
  flex: 1;
  
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;   /* Opera */
    text-overflow:    ellipsis;   /* IE, Safari (WebKit) */
    overflow:hidden;              /* don't show excess chars */
    white-space:nowrap;           /* force single line */
  
  /* this just added for better view */
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container > .item-2
{
  flex: 2;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">
    long text standing in here
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    more important text in here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that great answer! Unfortunately i'm killing the css of the parent if i'm changing the container to flex :/ !
Its a bit tricky because i'm using the mdl-framework (and i'm misusing the mdl chip a bit)

Comment: @naja08 you could add a child within the #item1 which then acts as the container. that should leave your #item1 as the normal container (like it is now) but just adds a flexbox "container" inside of it. Would that work?